# Firebase restrict read permission for only one child node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an  application using firebase and am running into some issues with the available security settings.
The data model for this application is very simple and is as follows-

```
posts : {
         "$postid":{
            "meta":{
                "state":true,
                "text" :"I should be read",
            },
            "likes":{uid1,uid2},
            "rating":{uid1,uid2},
            "comments":{uid1,uid2},
            "tag":{tag1,tag2},
            "category":{cat1,cat2},
            "status":{1},
            "content":{},
            "createdTime":{},
        }

    }
```

I have applied the below security settings :

```
"posts":
{
    ".read" : "auth != null",

    "$postid" :
    {
        "rating"{".write" : "auth != null"}

    }
}
```

I want to restrict read permission for an inner node "rating". How Can I apply this rule without changing the root node read rule ?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase rules filter down - so if you have a rule on the `postid` then it gives write access to the whole child object.

There are however two different ways to secure the content.

Option 1. Specify the expected object, I would suggest looking into [Data Validation](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/guide.md#data-validation) on Bolt.

Option 2. Is to specify each of the child objects with write permissions;

```
"posts": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$postid": {
    "meta": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "likes": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "comments": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "tag": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "category": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "status": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "content": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "createdTime": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

You'll need to adjust how you write to the object and it would create a lot of extra interactions with the database.

The ideal solution would be to move the rating to a different object such as;

```
"ratings": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$postid": { 
     // New location of the rating
  }
}
```